# Lookahead in ICU break rules

Tags: regex, tokenize, icu

I have a break rule that match wide variety of emoticons but also it yields some unnecessary matches, like '(Be' is matched as a smiley in '(Bellevue, WA)'

I'd like to improve it by adding a negative lookahead, e.g. if smiley ends with letter or digit there should be no letter or digit coming right after it.

I did it by adding a negative lookahead clause at the end of the break rule (before its numeric tag of course), but parsing fails.

Here is the simplified rule I try:
[\:][-] [()] (?![\w\d]) {451};

(it does not match '(Be' in my original example though)

So the questions are:

1. Are look-arounds supported for break rule? If yes what is the proper syntax?
2. If they are not supported what is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you don't get a response here, consider asking the icu-support list.